# What is "Job shadowing"?

Tags: company-culture, job-description

What is "job shadowing" ? Is it simply that a job shadower hovers around me, like a "shadow"?

Or is someone who is "job shadowing" akin to an intern, where I can offload some tasks to him/her?

In my case, I'm a consultant on a project . and the job shadower doesn't yet have a full-time role yet.  So it's as if he is interning

Comment: Is there a reason that you wouldn't ask whoever assigned the job shadower to you (or whoever is managing the project) to understand the goal of the project?  It's possible that the intention is to train this person in how to perform your tasks so they can support the process going forward.  It's possible that the goal is to give someone from another department insight into how certain tasks get accomplished.  Those goals (and many others) would involve very different approaches.

Comment: The answer covers this question quite well, but I wanted to comment on the offloading off work... I would say absolutely not. The whole point in job shadowing is so that someone sees what you are doing to get a better understanding of your processes and workflows. I don't think it should be used to train someone to do the job; that is what training is for.

Comment: @Ghost, on your account and that of an answer, job shadowing is a form of training. Now it is a narrower form of training, but as far as training in general is concerned, people learn best when they have (in classroom terms) both lectures to listen to and homework to work through. Now whether job shadowing *should* include something that benefits the learner the way standard homework does, is another question. But don't say "I don't think it should be used to do the job; that is what training is for" because job shadowing is a kind of training, and homework is pedagogically essential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Job Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shadow) is:

> "...a popular on-the-job learning, career development, and leadership development intervention. Essentially, job shadowing involves working with another employee who might have a different job in hand, might have something to teach, or can help the person shadowing him or her to learn new aspects related to the job, organization, certain behaviors or competencies."

So essentially, you are responsible for showing a worker how you do your job, so that they may better understand how to do it and learn to do it themselves.  This can be a part of teaching an intern or new hire, teaching an old worker a new job or skill set, sharpening a person's expertise in a particular subject that involves your work, or just teach someone what you do on your job so that they understand it better and how it fits into their own responsibilities.

In your specific case, you're teaching the job shadower how to perform the job that you're a consultant on, so that when you leave, they can do the job themselves (or better understand the processes behind it, depending on the exact job you have).

The reason it's called "shadowing" is because the person learning from you is meant to follow along with your own activity - some higher-level shadowing practices would have the learner performing the same tasks you do alongside you.  Others simply have the learner watch and then practice the job themselves later.